# Would an immigration case be opened if some required documents are missing?

Tags: immigration, canada

My brother and I applied few months ago for immigration  to Canada, we paid a lawyer to handle the process.

We had to provide him with many papers, he needs two more papers which we didn't give yet

- IELTS certification, we'll provide that in December, because the exam is scheduled then
- Work certificate, we'll provide that next month

Each month or so, my mom calls the lawyer to check upon the case, he tells her you have to wait few months. Today she called and he said you will receive an answer next month indicating whether the Canadian embassy agreed to open an immigration case or not.

I feel like he's lying, how could he give us an answer next month, if we need two months to give him all the required documents.

Would an immigration case be opened if some required documents are missing?

Comment: Are you sure the lawyer even applied? If so through what stream? Generally most (some exceptions apply) of the immigration streams in Canada require IELTS beforehand even before applying. If the application was rejected, then the only thing you can do is reapply.

Comment: @DipenShah Exactly, I really believe that the guy is just another scammer.

Comment: Ask for a case number or application number from the lawyer. If he really did apply, he should have this.

Comment: @okay then, would you please post an answer so that I could accept it? just to close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the lawyer even applied? If so through what stream? Generally most (some exceptions apply) of the immigration streams in Canada require IELTS beforehand even before applying. If the application was rejected, then the only thing you can do is reapply.

As a confirmation, you can ask for a case number or application number from the lawyer or even a UCI number in some cases to confirm if the lawyer actually applied on your behalf.